# If G compliment is disconnected, then chromatic number = circular chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've been reading through a book called graph homomorphism and this is an exercise I've been trying to prove.

Here's my work so far

Induction on number of vertices

Basis : this clearly holds

Induction :Let G have n+1 vertices. let X and Y be two sets in G compliment that have no edges between them. (since G compliment is disconnected these sets exist)

Consider the subgraph induced by G[X]. By induction hypothesis, the chromatic number = circular number of G[X]

Similarly for G[Y].

Since X, Y have no edges between them in G compliment, in G every vertex in X must be adjacent to every vertex in Y.

Therefore we can show the chromatic number of G = chromatic number of G[X] + G[Y] as every colour used in set X cannot be used on the vertices of set Y and vica versa. Now we just have to show that this is equal to the circular colouring.

Here's where I can't get anywhere so any help is appreciated.

Other approaches I took were to Induct on the chromatic number and then remove one of the partitions and see how it goes and a proof by contradiction using the circular arc definition.